# Trying to pass a link to image as string for POST web-request to send to API

Tags: c#, .net, api, post

I am making a program which uses the API to connect to a website. I need to upload an image to the chat of the website. Here is the API guide.

[image: API guide to add image to chat]

I have spent hours on this and keep getting this error. I can use the other APIs on their website to send text to the chat. But this API I cannot get to work.

JSON {"status":"error","timestamp":1574865576,"error":{"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}

Here is my code:

```
string file = "http://static.reddit.com/reddit.com.header.png";


//Variables body and theKey is used for request body, theKey holds generate hmac
var body = "apikey=" + apiKey + "&nonce=" + date + "&trade_hash=" + trade_hash + "&file=" + file;
var theKey = "&apiseal=" + hmac.GenerateHMAC(secret, body);

// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://paxful.com/api/trade-chat/image/add");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = body + theKey;
Console.WriteLine("POST is: "+postData);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.

request.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated. I've tried everything. I have also tried to contact the website but no response. Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify you are authorized? i.e. are you missing an auth header? Does the file link need to be https rather than http? I'm also a little confused on the content you are sending. Shouldn't your content type be "application/json" rather than plain text?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes Nick I am authorised. I can change the endpoint to send text to the chat and it works. If i add the content type to application/json it gives this error: Invalid Content-Type json, must be text\/plain.  I have also tried to use https in file link. But still no luck.

Comment: If it works as plaintext why are you trying to send it as json? You aren't sending it json, so why do you want to set it to json?

Comment: The accept header is JSON as the response from the website is in JSON whether or not the image was added to the chat successfully.

Comment: Ultimately only the api knows why you are forbidden.  We can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see assigment of your `byteArray` to request body. If you didn't miss it your question, it's likely that you are sending your post request without body, which may cause 403 - Forbidden.

Try to add something like:

```cs
var rs = request.GetRequestStream();
rs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Also you may consider using [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8). In that case your code would look like:

```cs
var content = new StringContent("postData", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
var http = new HttpClient();
var response = await http.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer if it helps anyone else. I had to URL encode the image URL as the API did not allow it as plain text.

So the it had to be:
http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.reddit.com%2Freddit.com.header.png

Instead of:
http://static.reddit.com/reddit.com.header.png